# How to fix Android SDK is outdated?

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, android-sdk-tools, android-sdk-manager

Any help with this error i have after updating unity to the latest version 2019.2.0f1 when building, its weird i have 29.0.1 SDK installed but the error says 25.2.5< 26.1.1 while actually i have the newest version of SDK 29.0.1 installed and the target API option in player settings is on Auto, i installed for second time SDK and change path in preference but still same error

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Images from SDK Manager to see installed files and versions

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

a proof for the comman line tools method i did

[image]

the new installed sdk files using the second method
[image]

Comment: Well, the two messages that say you're not using the recommended software are kinda a clue don't you think? Install AndroidStudio and install the Android SDK from there. https://developer.android.com/studio#downloads

Comment: i said that i installed it u can see the folder of newest version and i did that using SDK Manager cause i had android studio before and i did it again to verify using command line tool

Comment: You showed one version, build tools, yet there are four. Build Tools, Platform Tools, SDK Tools, and the actual SDK. In your case, SDK Tools seems out of date, but I'd guess the others could be as well. When you update all of them you'll be fine. Good luck.

Comment: i updated images i think i have all files and as i said i unstalled them again using commande line in another folder but still same 25.2.5< 26.1.1 , i don't even now why its exactly 25.2.5 and  26.1.1 while the api target was auto

Comment: It has nothing to do with your target. Unity requires a newer version of the SDK tools. You don't have it.

Comment: if you took a look about my updated sdk manager installed files images you will find that Android SDK Platform Tools 29.0.2 is installed , isit not the sdk tools file you mean ?

Comment: Take a look at the top line of tools. Notice the version. Notice the error. You're using old tools that can't update themselves. Use Android Studio to get the current versions. Either that or keep explaining why it should be working when it isn't and it has been explained to you why several times.

Comment: Did you try to simply use the SDK and JDK installed "built-in" with Unity?

Comment: derHugo if you mean to check the box in preference yes i did but same error appear 25.2.5<26.1.1

Comment: @Retired Ninja dude for the Android SDK tools 25.2.5 in SDK Manager i uninstalled it and its the only sdk tools version thats showed for me in SDK Manager when i tried to install only Android SDK Platform-tools 29.0.2 it alwayse install with it SDK tools 25.2.5 i don't know why its maybe a bug in sdk manager ,

Comment: @Retired Ninja and i tried another method i downloaded android command line tools developer.android.com/studio/index.html#command-tools and i did all this commands forum.unity.com/threads/guide-android-sdk-tools-installation-cli.598717/ to get a new folder of sdk files and put it in the preference path but same error appears  25.2.5<26.1.1 with same number

Answer (score 1, accepted):

finally after the Second attempt of trying to install the Android SDK Using command line tools [Sdk Tools For Android Command line Tools](https://developer.android.com/studio/index.html#command-tools) and then following this guide here [SDK tools installation](https://forum.unity.com/threads/guide-android-sdk-tools-installation-cli.598717/) (to get safe from sdkmanage.bat --list  error open CMD by tab + right click inside Tools/bin foolder and select Open PowerShell Window here to start the cmd directly from that folder) , but in this second attempt i installed "build-tools;28.0.3" and "platforms;android-29" , im not sure why it didn't work from the first attempt when i installed the newest build tools 29.0.1 using SDK Manager and Using Command line tools.